# PostgreSQL query optimisation using index on timestamp columns and GREATEST function

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, query-performance, postgresql-9.5

Needing to speed up a query I am running. Unsure of appropriate index to add. Would appreciate some ideas. Note that the output below is for a small subset of my data. The actual table is much larger. The actual query takes around 15 minutes to run.

Query:

```
SELECT  last_known_position_timestamp,
        mmsi,
        name,
        row_number()  OVER (PARTITION BY mmsi, date_trunc('hour', GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp) ) + INTERVAL '1 hours'
                        ORDER BY GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)  DESC) AS row_number
FROM    test
WHERE   date_trunc('hour', GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp) ) + INTERVAL '1 hours' > timezone('UTC', now()) - INTERVAL '672 hours'
```

Explain:

```
"WindowAgg  (cost=137178.97..149678.96 rows=333333 width=263)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=137178.97..138012.31 rows=333333 width=248)"
"        Sort Key: mmsi, ((date_trunc('hour'::text, GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)) + '01:00:00'::interval)), (GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)) DESC"
"        ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..78931.33 rows=333333 width=248)"
"              Filter: ((date_trunc('hour'::text, GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)) + '01:00:00'::interval) > (timezone('UTC'::text, now()) - '672:00:00'::interval))"
```

Thank you!

**EDIT 1: Was asked to give EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE so here it is.**

```
"WindowAgg  (cost=109508.97..120342.30 rows=333333 width=48) (actual time=561.804..561.804 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Output: last_known_position_timestamp, mmsi, name, row_number() OVER (?), (GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)), ((date_trunc('hour'::text, GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)) + '01:00:00'::interval))"
"  Buffers: shared hit=48098"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=109508.97..110342.31 rows=333333 width=40) (actual time=558.182..558.182 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Output: mmsi, (GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)), ((date_trunc('hour'::text, GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)) + '01:00:00'::interval)), last_known_position_timestamp, name"
"        Sort Key: test.mmsi, ((date_trunc('hour'::text, GREATEST(test.last_known_position_timestamp, test.predicted_position_timestamp)) + '01:00:00'::interval)), (GREATEST(test.last_known_position_timestamp, test.predicted_position_timestamp)) DESC"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=48098"
"        ->  Seq Scan on vessel.test  (cost=0.00..78931.33 rows=333333 width=40) (actual time=558.174..558.175 rows=0 loops=1)"
"              Output: mmsi, GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp), (date_trunc('hour'::text, GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)) + '01:00:00'::interval), last_known_position_timestamp, name"
"              Filter: ((date_trunc('hour'::text, GREATEST(test.last_known_position_timestamp, test.predicted_position_timestamp)) + '01:00:00'::interval) > (timezone('UTC'::text, now()) - '672:00:00'::interval))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 1000000"
"              Buffers: shared hit=48098"
"Planning Time: 0.098 ms"
"Execution Time: 561.865 ms"
```

**EDIT 2:**

Was asked about the date_trunc section. For the output I need I want my data rounded to the hour. So 16:04 becomes 17:00, and 17:45 becomes 18:00 etc.

The table I am selecting the data from has months of data in. But I only want the last 4 weeks ( taking the rounding into account). So I am doing this

```
date_trunc('hour', GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp) ) + INTERVAL '1 hours' > timezone('UTC', now()) - INTERVAL '672 hours' > timezone('UTC', now()) - INTERVAL '672 hours' –
```

The process is complicated because sometimes the vessels I'm tracking have an actual location, and sometimes it's predicted. I have to take whichever is most recent. Hence the 'GREATEST' part of the query.

**EDIT 3**

I added an index as below:

```
CREATE INDEX test_index ON test ((date_trunc('hour', GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)) + INTERVAL '1 hours'))
```

Then ran explain again, and it seems to have marginally lowered the cost.

```
"WindowAgg  (cost=97521.39..108354.72 rows=333333 width=48)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=97521.39..98354.73 rows=333333 width=40)"
"        Sort Key: mmsi, ((date_trunc('hour'::text, GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)) + '01:00:00'::interval)), (GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)) DESC"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=4413.76..66943.75 rows=333333 width=40)"
"              Recheck Cond: ((date_trunc('hour'::text, GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)) + '01:00:00'::interval) > (timezone('UTC'::text, now()) - '672:00:00'::interval))"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_index  (cost=0.00..4330.43 rows=333333 width=0)"
"                    Index Cond: ((date_trunc('hour'::text, GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp)) + '01:00:00'::interval) > (timezone('UTC'::text, now()) - '672:00:00'::interval))"
```

Comment: `date_trunc` and the addition of the interval seem pointless. How would they influence the result? Can you provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)` output?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe -- Have added EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) and information about the date_trunc .

Answer (score 0):

All your time is spent in the sequential scan, and probably a lot of it in repeatedly executing the same functions.

You should create an index on the expression on the left side of the `=` in the `WHERE` condition. This might not be possible as it is if your timestamps are of type `timestamp with time zone`. In that case, you have to convert the timestamp to a `timestamp without time zone` using the `AT TIME ZONE` construct first.

Comment: My timestamps do not have a timezone. Well, they are UTC, but they are stored as just 'timestamp'.

So I should try to create an index on the following?.......

date_trunc('hour', GREATEST(last_known_position_timestamp, predicted_position_timestamp) ) + INTERVAL '1 hours'

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can also simplify the expression in the `OVER` clause.